# extension crash on exporting stringified/encodeURIComponent data to file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, stringify, encodeuricomponent

It is about exporting extension data from options page.
I have array of objects, with stored page screenshots encoded in base64, and some other minor obj properties. I'm trying to export them with this code:

```
exp.onclick = expData;

function expData() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('extData', function (result) {
        var dataToSave = result.extData;
        var strSt = JSON.stringify(dataToSave);
        downloadFn('extData.txt', strSt);
    }); 
}

function downloadFn(filename, text) {
    var fLink = document.createElement('a');
    fLink .setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    fLink .setAttribute('download', filename);
    fLink .click();

}
```

On button click, get data from storage, stringify it, create fake link, set attributes and click it.
Code works fine if resulting file is **under ~1.7 MB**, but everything above that produce option page to crash and extension gets disabled.
I can `console.log(strSt)` after `JSON.stringify` and everything works fine no matter of the size, if I don't pass it to download function..
Is there anything I can do to fix the code and avoid crash?...or is there any limitation is size when using this methods?

Comment: If it's a proper crash it should be reported to Chrome team at https://crbug.com/ (try to [enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and see the exact error)

Comment: That said, it's probably a limitation of this particular method. I'm sure it's not the only method, but unfortunately I don't have off the top of my head.

Comment: You could try [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) instead of constructing a DOM element.

Comment: use `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ text ]))` to feed the href instead of a data: url

Comment: ok, tnx all for comments...I will try something based on your comments, but tomorrow (too late now), and post result if worked or not. Bug reporting is last resort :)

Comment: @dandavis 'URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ text ]))' also produces crash of extension

Comment: @Xan 'chrome.downloads' works fine

Comment: _Crash_ bug reporting is the only responsible choice. What if it's maliciously exploitable? Would you like me to make that into an answer? I'll be fine if you self-answer with your resulting code.

Comment: I just answered my own q... :)

Comment: but not sure how to describe it in bug report...it needs extension code to be tested

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure you can produce a minimal example and test it in Chrome Canary (to see if it's fixed already in a future version). You can include a .zip of a test extension with the bug report.

Comment: ughhh..I was afraid of that... I will make something today :) (canary also crashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this, as Xan suggested, switching to `chrome.downloads` (it's extra permission, but works fine)
What I did is just replacing code in `downloadFN` function, it's cleaner that way

```
function downloadFn(filename, text) {
    var eucTxt = encodeURIComponent(text);
    chrome.downloads.download({'url': 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,'+eucTxt, 'saveAs': false, 'filename': filename});

}
```

<strike>note that using `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ text ]))` also produce same crashing of extension</strike>

**EDIT:**
as @dandavis pointed (and RobW confirmed), converting to Blob also works
(I had messed code that was producing crash)
This is a better way of saving data locally, because on browser internal downloads page, dataURL downloads can clutter page and if file is too big (long URL), it crashes browser. They are presented as actual URLs (which is raw saved data) while blob downloads are only with id

```
function downloadFn(filename, text) {
    var vLink = document.createElement('a'),
    vBlob = new Blob([text], {type: "octet/stream"}),
    vUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(vBlob);
    vLink.setAttribute('href', vUrl);
    vLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
    vLink.click();
}
```

Comment: The crash is caused by the long URL. There are many bug reports on the issue tracker, e.g. https://crbug.com/69227. Using `URL.createObjectURL` would work around the issue though, so I'm surprised that you assert that the crash doesn't go away if you use `URL.createObjectURL` + `Blob`.

Comment: I didn't forget to reply, I just couldn't make it to work that day, and didn't had time to find problem. It turned out that I had double (old) code within the same file and old "way" was causing crashes. And then later old downloads API make it to work, but that wasn't actual code with blob :)... nabs mistakes when rushing thins...I'l update my answer